# EventHubTrigger EventData[] binding not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am making a C# Isolated worker process Azure Function triggered by an EventHub that will output a list of `EventData` with headers into an other EventHub.

The Function works well when using the `string[]` binding but when I am using the binding `EventData` from `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` the function throw the following messages in the console:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.MyFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'eventDatas'. Azure.Core.Amqp: Serialization failed due to an unsupported type, System.Byte[].
Executed 'Functions.MyFunction' (Failed, Id=4a2fcfa1-0042-4cb8-92d6-75289685b4dd, Duration=15ms)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.MyFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'eventDatas'. Azure.Core.Amqp: Serialization failed due to an unsupported type, System.Byte[].
```

#### Project file

```xml
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>

    ...

    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.9.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="5.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
```

#### Function code

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using my.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace my.function
{
    public class MyFunction
    {
        [EventHubOutput("EventHubOutput", Connection = "EventHubOutputConnectionString")]
        [FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:00:10")]
        [Function("MyFunction")]
        public EventData[] Run([EventHubTrigger("EventHubInput", Connection = "EventHubInputConnectionString", IsBatched = true)] EventData[] eventDatas)
        {
            List<EventData> eventDataOutputs = new List<EventData> { };

            // Receive events
            foreach (EventData eventData in eventDatas)
            {
                // Serialize the event
                string eventJsonBody = eventData.EventBody.ToString();
                MyObject? myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(eventJsonBody);

                // Append nested elements
                if (myObject != null)
                {
                    eventDataOutputs.AddRange(myObject.nestedElements.Select(nestedElement => new EventData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nestedElement))));
                }
            }
            return eventDataOutputs.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyObject class

```cs
namespace my.Models
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class MyObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("randomField")]
        public string RandomField { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nestedFields")]
        public NestedField[] NestedFields { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### NestedField class

```cs
namespace my.Models
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class NestedField
    {
        [JsonProperty("randomFieldNested")]
        public string RandomField { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("longField")]
        public long LongField { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Update

I tried on a newer EventHubs and I received events.

Comment: can you please share MyObject class

Comment: It seems like the EventData.Properties contains a property whose value is a byte array, which is not one of the [supported types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.properties?view=azure-dotnet#remarks). How were these EventData instances send to the event hub?

Answer (score 1):

*I have made few modification in your code and it worked for me*

**`Code:`**

```
[Function(nameof(Function1))]
        [FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:00:10")]
        [EventHubOutput("eventHubOutput", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]
        public EventData[] Run([EventHubTrigger("eventhubinput", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting", IsBatched = true)] EventData[] events)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Received {events.Length} events");
            List<EventData> eventDataOutputs = new List<EventData>();
            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                string eventJsonBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.EventBody);

                MyObject[]? myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject[]>(eventJsonBody);

                if (myObjects != null)
                {
                    foreach (MyObject myObject in myObjects)
                    {
                        if (myObject.NestedFields != null)
                        {
                            foreach (NestedField nestedField in myObject.NestedFields)
                            {
                                // Extract field values from the NestedField object
                                string randomFieldNested = nestedField.RandomField;
                                DateTimeOffset time = nestedField.Time;
                                long longField = nestedField.LongField;

                                // Create a new EventData instance with the extracted field values
                                string eventDataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                                {
                                    RandomFieldNested = randomFieldNested,
                                    Time = time,
                                    LongField = longField
                                });
                                EventData newEventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eventDataJson));

                                // Add the new EventData to the output list
                                eventDataOutputs.Add(newEventData);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("Data Processed.....");
            return eventDataOutputs.ToArray();

        }
```

**`Output:`**

[image]