# EventHubTrigger with EventData[] binding not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am making a C# Isolated worker process Azure Function triggered by an EventHub.

The Function works well when using the string[] binding but when I am using the binding EventData from Azure.Messaging.EventHubs the function throw the following messages in the console:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: EventHubFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'eventDatas'. Azure.Core.Amqp: Serialization failed due to an unsupported type, System.Byte[].
```

Project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.9.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="6.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.15.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder _) => { })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Function code:

```
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class EventHubFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public EventHubFunction(ILogger<EventHubFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(EventHubFunction)]
        public void Run([EventHubTrigger(Constants.EventHub, Connection = Constants.Connection, ConsumerGroup = Constants.ConsumerGroup, IsBatched = true)] EventData[] eventDatas)
        {
            foreach (var eventData in eventDatas)
            {
                 //processing message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It never reaches inside of the method.

There is exactly same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76882371/eventhubtrigger-eventdata-binding-not-working/) but I already have newest version of libraries.

**Update:**

1 of the system properties keys is **x-opt-kafka-key**. Using in-process model with following package works as expected so it looks its some kind of issue with isolated worker or I have missed something.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="6.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering, "Azure.Core.Amqp: Serialization failed due to an unsupported type, System.Byte[]," indicates that there's an issue with the data serialization while binding the `EventData` from the Azure.Messaging.EventHubs. The problem seems to be related to the data type or serialization process.

Error you're encountering is related to the Azure Function trying to deserialize the `EventData` object, which is not directly supported. Instead, Azure Functions with the Event Hubs trigger use custom deserialization for Event Hubs messages. You should bind your function to the `EventData` object and then extract the message from it.

Here is the code im able to acheive to hit method

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    namespace MyFunctionApp
    {
        public class EventHubFunction
        {
            private readonly ILogger<EventHubFunction> _logger;
    
            public EventHubFunction(ILogger<EventHubFunction> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }
    
            [Function("EventHubFunction")]
            public void Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnection")] EventData[] events)
            {
                foreach (var eventData in events)
                {
                    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.EventBody.ToArray());
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Received message: {message}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code, we bind the `EventData` directly, and then we extract the message body as a string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventHubMessage.EventBody.ToArray())`

**Result**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not working for me. When I am using EventData as input parameter (in batch or not in batch) the body of the method is never reached (even when the body is empty).